# listening comprehension. (what does it say in a drama clip?)

Tags: listening-comprehension

I'm studying german and using a drama "Die Susanne". It's on the youtube.
In this drama clip, a boy tries to fix his bike and when he thinks it's done, he finds it still doesn't work. so he shouts something in exclamation and the girl asks "Was machst du denn?".
What does the boy say before she asked?
listen to this clip. it's at about 30 seconds. (you can use space bar to stop or go, or use mouse).
Thanks!
https://clyp.it/4outrfv1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the boy says

> Ach, Mann - Mist!

what is roughly

> Oh, man - crap!

Comment: Ah, thank you! it's good that I can ask native speakers!

Comment: The *Mann* had been clipped by the microphone volume control because he thrashed his bike the very same moment. But it's the only word which fits in – it's a fixed expression.

Comment: I don't hear a *Mann*. I think it's more something like "Ach m-mist".